# Is string args[] in java implemented as varargs?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, variadic-functions, args

How `public static void main(String args[])`'s `String args[]` is implemented? Is it implemented as `varargs`?

I am asking this because `args.length` gives only the number of arguments passed , which means it is not defined anywhere like `String args[] = new String[30]`. How is this array implemented ?

Comment: It's `public static void main(String[] args)`...

Comment: @nkr both `String[] args` and `String args[]` are equivalent notations for the same thing - one parameter whose type is an array of `String`

Answer (score 12):

It's implemented exactly as it looks - as an array of strings. Varargs, on the other hand, is implemented as an array – `String...` is just syntactic sugar for `String[]`.

Answer (score 4):

It is declared (not implemented) however *you* say it is declared. It's perfectly legal for you to declare the function using varargs:

```
public static void main(String... argv)
```

The compiler takes a varargs declaration and converts it to `String[]` in the bytecode. This happens for *all* functions that use varargs.

When the JVM starts running your program, it creates an array that is exactly as long as the number of command-line arguments (excluding any arguments like `-D` that are intended for the JVM itself). Then it searches for a main function in the specified class and invokes it.

Answer (score 2):

It's just an array of strings which is initialized with the values of the arguments passed to the process when started. It's not a variable arguments list.